# Issue when using InstallCert For SSLCertification

Tags: java, server, http-post, ssl-certificate

I was trying to send a post request on a url from server then it showed following errors

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
 valid   certification path to requested target
```

Then I found about InstallCert.java( https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs56/examples/ldap/SimpleQuery/InstallCert.java  ) which will allow my host and port to send the request. But when I was trying to run it on server it also showed some errors.

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-14:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps$ java InstallCert 52.39.134.231:8080
 Loading KeyStore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts...
 Opening connection to 52.39.134.231:8080...
```

Starting SSL handshake...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:91)
 Could not obtain server certificate chain
```

And now I don't know what to do to send my request.

Comment: Nmap scan report for ec2-52-39-134-231.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (52.39.134.231)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
8080/tcp open   http-proxy - no open https ports on this server

Comment: can you elaborate a little more about "no open https port on this server"

Comment: You didn't configure https connector in tomcat config. Usually it listen port 8443. Right now server can't work on https protocol, and you trying to use `https` but connect to `http` port (8080). That is a reason why you get 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?'