# Configuring Tomcat with SSL on server

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, server, tomcat7

I am trying to configure tomcat with the SSL on server (Because i need to make a request through https).
I followed these steps-:
1). generating a keystore

```
  $Tomcat\bin>keytool -genkey -alias mkyong -keyalg RSA -keystore    
  c:\mkyongkeystore
  Enter keystore password:
  Re-enter new password:
  What is your first and last name?
   [Unknown]:  yong mook kim
  What is the name of your organizational unit?
  //omitted to save space
  [no]:  yes

  Enter key password for <mkyong>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
  Re-enter new password:

   $Tomcat\bin>
```

2). configuring tomcat with keystore by adding a connector In server.xml

```
       <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/key/mykeystore"
       keystorePass="password" />
```

then I tried to open the https://[host]:8443/
But its still shows This page can’t be displayed

But when I tried the same method for localhost then it worked.
Why its not working on  server
[image: WEB PAGE]

[image]

Comment: You added the SSL config to the connector that is listening on port 8080 and tried to access tomcat on port 8443? That won't work. Either add a second connector for a different port (f.e. 8443) for SSL or use 8080, if you don't need to support HTTPS and HTTP connections.

Comment: that's just a misprint . sorry for that

Comment: Do you have some firewall in place that blocks access to port 8443 from remote? It may as well be possible that another process is already listening on 8443.  If this is the case, there should be an error in the tomcat logs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814861/issue-when-using-installcert-for-sslcertification This was my main problem, But I got a comment to configure port with SSL

Comment: Any suggestions @user1516873

Comment: From the other question I see that you are on AWS. Perhaps you need to open port 8443 in the security groups for your server otherwise you won't be able to connect to your instance on this port. Alternatively you could run SSL on another port that already accepts connections (like 443 or 8080)

Comment: yeah I have opened that(8443) port and also tried to add connector on 8080 ,

Comment: But its still not showing webpage

Comment: Could you please show the exact error message, and/or say what composant is sending it (browser, tomcat, ...)?

Comment: I have edited it !

Comment: I did use 8080  because I followed the second last comment of @dpr and configured 8080 on the place of 8443

Comment: Could you add the tomcat log output. I thing it's catalina<timestamp>.log And have you been able to connect to your tomcat server over HTTP on port 8080 before you changed the connector for this port to HTTPS?

Comment: yeah 8080 with http is working fine

Comment: How about the log files?

Comment: i'm adding logs file tell me which one

Comment: I think catalina.out

Comment: it doesn't show any entry of today

Comment: How do you start tomcat? Try to ssh on the machine and start using `catalina.sh run` and add the output to your question

Comment: I don't know why but this morning it started working . I think tomcat was not working right . Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

I think better you can redirect the tomcat port to IIS,in IIS you can easily enable HTTPS.

https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Comment: from the shell commands in the initial post I'd guess that @Mudit is not working on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quotes from Tomcat documentation on setting HTTPS:

> Tomcat can use two different implementations of SSL:
>
> the JSSE implementation provided as part of the Java runtime (since 1.4)
>   
>     the APR implementation, which uses the OpenSSL engine by default.
> ...
>
> As configuration attributes for SSL support significantly differ between APR vs. JSSE implementations, it is recommended to avoid auto-selection of implementation. It is done by specifying a classname in the protocol attribute of the Connector.
>
> To define a Java (JSSE) connector, regardless of whether the APR library is loaded or not, use one of the following:

> ```
> <!-- Define a HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443, JSSE NIO implementation -->
> <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
>        port="8443" .../>
> ```

My understanding on that is that you should try to use a classname for the protocol attribute:

```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
   keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/key/mykeystore"
   keystorePass="password" />
```

Comment: it was just a misprint in question.

Comment: And this is the same thing I used on localhost and its working. But on server its not:(\